# ajax call to mvc3 controller always returning an error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have written a jquery ajax function that I have added to js file

I am using mvc3 as my server technology. my controller is getting hit with the data expected and I am able to debug through my controller code and nothing goes wrong there.

However the success event is never hit and everytime only the error function is ever called.

```
function processTransaction(json, et, ta, cardId, id, url, insertId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: { insertId: insertId, amount: ta, cardId: cardId, type: et, Id: id},
        success: function () {
            console.log("sweeeeet");
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e);
            console.log("fail");
        }
    });
}
```

Is there something blinding that im doing wrong?

I have added an image of the full error from the developer console.

[image]

Comment: Look at your javascript debugging console. FireBug for example will show you the server response. What is it? What is the status code? Maybe something went wrong with the execution of the action result? We cannot know this as you haven't shown your code.

Comment: statusCode: function (a){if(a){var b;if(s<2)for(b in a)j[b]=[j[b],a[b]];else b=a[v.status],v.then(b,b)}return this}
statusText: "error"

Comment: I only have chrome but the above is the status code.

Comment: look at the `Network` tab. There you will see the AJAX request and explore the response.

Comment: The order I would check things: 1) make sure that js is making a request. 2. Find out the exact URL that it's requesting 3) check the routes and see where that request is going 4) check the controller constructor 5) check the action to make sure it's not throwing an exception. There are a few more places to look, but usually you'll find it in those first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there something blinding that im doing wrong?

Your client code is valid!
You get an exception on the server.

Change the last line of your controller action to see what is going on:

```
var x = Json(...); // You will get an exception here...

return x;
```

Comment: But im not getting on the server. Thats whats got me so confused.

Comment: @DiverDan. try changing the last line like I suggested.

Comment: @gdoron, no, not a very long. Suffice to say `Your client code is valid! You get an exception on the server.` -> fits perfectly for a comment.

Comment: @DiverDan, the fact that your controller action is hit doesn't mean that the AJAX request will succeed. Don't forget that executing a controller action is only part of the pipeline. After there is execution of the underlying view. So look at the `Network` tab in your Chrome developer toolbar and tell me what it says.

Comment: Hey @DarinDimitrov within the network tab I can see that the post to my controller status text is shown as Canceled. The response is empty

Answer (score 0):

In my case i put the date time in the end

```
<img src="@Url.Action("ShowPhoto", "Tool", new { id = Model.Id })?@DateTime.Now" class="fixed_img img-thumbnail">
```

93!